# jQuery DatePicker: currentDate does not work when the date field is 12-31-9999

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

The DatePicker does not properly handle the calculation of the currentDate when both the current field value is 12-31-9999 and the yearRange is 2000:+1. The result for the currentDate becomes 1-1-2000 when I click on the field to open DatePicker. So, it appears that DatePicker wraps the date around to the start of the yearRange. But, if I remove the yearRange, then DatePicker defaults to a range of -10:+10, which results in the year being 9989:10009.

I would much rather have the DatePicker show today's date when I click on the field that contains 12-31-9999. Note: no change should be made when escaping out of the field. Is this possible?

```
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        yearRange: 2000:+1
    });
```

Comment: "the field that contains 12-31-9999."...surely the real question is why do your fields contain junk dates instead of NULL?

Comment: The date of 12-31-9999 is not a junk date - it is used as an end date, which is paired up with a real start date. The purpose for doing it this way is to search for records between a specific date without having to include ISNULL in the predicate.

Comment: I see, it's one way to do it I guess but as you've seen it causes other issues. If there's no set end date, then from a data quality point of view the recommended approach would be to use NULL, most people would argue that not having to put ISNULL into a query is not sufficient reason to pollute the data with dates that are not really real. It's then much harder for other parts of your program, such as the datepicker, to distinguish between what is a meaningful date and what is just a placeholder to be ignored. That's best practice, but it's a matter of opinion ultimately.

Comment: With all due respect, I did not post a question to litigate the validity of a 'junk' date. More so, the DatePicker demonstrates inconsistent behavior where it rolls over the date to the beginning when a date is 12-31-9999 AND the yearRange is 2000:+1, yet it keeps incrementing years beyond 9999 when a yearRange is not specified. Is this a bug within datepicker or am I specifying a bad yearRange?

Comment: My reason for raising it was that it's arguably an example of an X-Y problem (http://xyproblem.info/) - looking for a solution to an problem which wouldn't exist if you'd done something else differently to begin with. If you just had blank/null instead of these bogus end dates (no event or time period really ends in 9999, no user actually wanted or asked for that in real life, let's be clear) then the problem with the datepicker would just go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because the date in your input field ("9999-12-31") is outside the range you've specified ("2000:+1"). This range produces dates from 2000-2019 (the end year is today's year plus one, as per the spec).

Also you said "But, if I remove the yearRange, then DatePicker defaults to a range of -10:+10". Not quite. It defaults to "c-10:c+10" which if you look at the spec, is not quite the same thing - the "c" means it places the range at 10 years +/- the year in the input, as opposed to today's year.

I think this misunderstanding has led to your mistake. If you want it to display the 9999 date then set the year range to

```
yearRange: "2000:c+1"
```

This will set the max year as the input year +1, as opposed to today's year +1.

See http://jsfiddle.net/5ornc4gv/7/ for a demo.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange contains details of the format string.

As I remarked in the comments though, this would be a less of an issue if your software used NULL to represent the "end date" of periods of time with no realistic define end date. Also the year drop-down-list in the datepicker which produced by your year range is hard to use and might cause a bit of a lag in some browsers due to the amount of data in it.